# What is the best way to get count of dictionary values matching expression?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, iteration

I need to iterate over all dictionary values in a dictionary of type:

Dictionary<Vector3, bool>

and get the number of entries that have bool == true;

Currently, I am doing this:

```
int walkableTiles = 0;

        foreach (bool walkable in region.RegionPositions.Values)
        {
            if (walkable) walkableTiles++;
        }
        
        Debug.Log("walkable tiles new " + walkableTiles);
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: By "efficient", do you mean "shorter code"?

Comment: Shorter, or faster.

Comment: If you mean a shorter code, you can use linq which basically does the same enumeration that you are doing manually: int walkableTiles = region.RegionPositions.Count(k=>k);

Comment: var count = region.RegionPositions.Count(e => e.Value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want shorter code, you can use [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__):

```
int walkableTiles = region.RegionPositions.Values.Count(x => x);
```

In terms of speed though, there really isn't any faster way to know how many elements in a collection are `true`, other than to count them one by one. This is what you are doing with your code, and [what `Count` does](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1329) under the hood too. Assuming that you actually have a performance problem, there are probably better places you can optimise, than counting `true`s.

Comment: Implementing this exact code gives me the error:
Method, delegate or event is expected

 How do I use Count to return all Values which are True?

Comment: @franticabyss Did you do `using System.Linq;`? You should do that.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, with the data structure you're using, you will have to iterate every element. You can do it in *less code* but not *more efficiently*.

```
var walkableTiles = region.RegionPositions.Count(x => x.Value);
```

You might consider having a data structure that keeps a running count of true's if this is something you do often.